# How do the rich and wealthy withdraw from accounts without leaving home?

Tags: banking, financial-literacy, withdrawal, ultra-rich

I was at someone's house once and they made a phone call and had someone bring $50,000.00 cash to their home from one of their bank accounts. I think the person worked for the bank and wasn't a relative with their name on the account.

Comment: Just curious: why would anyone need $50000 in cash delivered at home on a short notice?

Comment: If you are close enough to this person for them to make this phone call while you are in the room, you can certainly ask them your question.

Comment: @EricDuminil Poker explains both why they need the cash and why they don't want to leave the table to make the call.

Comment: To the angry people: I was working on their home network. It would of been an idiot move to ask..

Comment: @user1276423, best to just ignore silly comments on this site.  It's impossible to provide an answer unless you give the country.

Comment: @user1276423 Be careful about overinterpreting. None of the responses was "angry", and your explanation of being an employee/contractor is quite reasonable.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking if a `rich and wealthy` person is able to pay for services that an "average" person can't afford? From very close personal experience, I say "Yes". Or are you asking if a `rich and wealthy` person might have $50k in a business safe or similar and have an office manager transport it? Answer seems obvious. Or are you certain that it was a 'normal' deposit account?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Many services are available to people who are wealthy enough to use [private banks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_banking). The linked Wikipedia article says:

> ...banking services (deposit taking and payments), discretionary asset
>   management, brokerage, limited tax advisory services and some basic
>   concierge-type services, offered by a single designated relationship
>   manager.

Having cash delivered to your door would come under "basic concierge-type services".

Comment: Minor note- the article makes a distinction between private _banks_ and private _banking_.

Comment: So what, "basic concierge-type services" is the banking equivalent of "other duties as assigned"?

Comment: "Many services are available to people who are wealthy".  Man, that's the truth.  +1

Comment: Don't be critical.. You go to a job and do other things for the same currency.. Everyone is trying to get currency from an employer or other people.. We don't trade furs anymore so none of us have a choice..

Comment: **If this is in the USA**, I very much doubt that a private banking service, would include this function.

Comment: @user1276423, I didn't see any criticism in either the answer or the comments.  What are you referring to?  Perhaps this illustrates your own mindset more than that of the other commenter?  :)  If you meant the "Man, that's the truth" comment, my own thought on reading that was, "Yes, that's one reason why it is a *good thing* to become wealthy."  (But then, I doubt I would have read it the same before reading books by Grant Cardone!)

Comment: "Man, that's the truth" could be seen as criticism, but I'm not trying to confuse anyone.. I'm obviously talking about the US. I'm not sure how this confuses people so much..

Comment: Just to follow up, a cursory google search found many examples of US banks that offer a service with an armored car company to move cash to and from a customer's location, both on a regular route and on demand.  It appears to be oriented towards retail business customers, but there's no reason a wealthy individual couldn't use this.

Answer (score 16):

This is a facility called Home Banking, which banks in some locations offer. You do not necessarily have to be super-rich to use it though.

[Kotak Mahindra Bank has been offering it here in India for about 10 years now](http://www.kotak.com/sites/default/files/press_release/home_banking_0.pdf). Other banks have followed suit with similar offerings.

I am not super-rich or anywhere close<sup>1</sup>, but I have used this facility occasionally when I couldn't visit an ATM or the branch, to either get cash delivered to me, or to deposit cash into my account.

The banks do charge a convenience fee for this facility as you might expect, but they waive it off if your average monthly balance exceeds a certain amount.

Not sure about how it works in other countries, but here in India, if you have an account with one of the top customer-friendly banks, this facility is as mundane as a cheque book or a debit card.

---

<sup>1</sup> If I were, I probably wouldn't be posting here. ;-)

Comment: The OP didn't add a country tag, but since they used the $ symbol, we can narrow down their target country list, to something that doesn't include India.

Comment: @stannius: What exactly would work differently about the service in dollar-places compared to the described service in India? I fail to see why an answer describing such a service in, say, Belize would be more helpful than one describing such a service in India, if the OP sits in, say, the US or in Australia.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's not the point. The point is that we can't rule out the possibility that the OP is in fact in Belize, but we can rule out India.

Comment: @Relaxed: And my point is that this answer is not specific to India. It describes the concept in general terms (as does the answer that has meanwhile been accepted), and provides a concrete example of such a service as a proof that this kind of thing exists somewhere on the world.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper That's a very roundabout way to make your point, then. But in any case, it is specific to India, that's the problem! It gives no reason to believe this exists elsewhere.

Comment: Anyone reading this probably knows nobody with a decent net-worth at least is reading about money on the internet unless it's stats on investments..

Comment: @stannius You mean this service which exists in India for 10 years doesn't exist in "dollar" countries even now? I guess my point here was that such a service being in existence for a decade in a "third world" country sort of *implies* that it is a standard service that banks in the more advanced countries would offer.

Comment: Besides, the dollar sign is not really a critical ingredient of the question. We should try to make the question as generically applicable as possible, without conflicting with the OP's problem, so you can as well edit it to "How do rich people get banks to bring large amounts of money home?", and then this answer attempts to show that it is not really something to be surprised about. If I asked, "I saw a rich guy transfer money from one account to another over the internet! How did they do that?", the answer would be, "Duh! that's called internet banking." This is no different.

Comment: I think "Super-rich people don't answer questions[...]" is based on a **misconception**: You would not know if they did - they do not behave "super-rich" (there are exceptions I chose to ignore). Why not answering a question that is easy for the person? Note that it may be more motivating to earn some **reputation points** at SE, than earning some more money, if you **no longer care** about how much you have!

Comment: @VolkerSiegel That was a bit of a tongue-in-cheek joke based on a common meme which goes something like, "If I had that much money, I wouldn't be wasting time here on the internet." :-)

Comment: @Relaxed: "it is specific to India" - I disagree. I see it as an answer that is as generic as the accepted answer. It also provides a concrete example that *happens to be* from India. As it stands, the accepted answer "gives no reason to believe this exists" in any particular place, either. Note that I'm not claiming this should be the accepted answer, or that this answer is any more elaborate than the others. I just find it nonsensical to dismiss an answer on the basis that it contains a concrete example for the *existence* of a described concept, without any claim that that particular ...

Comment: ... example is the very service the OP has observed while they were "at someone's house". If we want to go into nitpicky territory like this, though, please provide some proof that the OP was not watching someone getting delivered some *foreign currency* within India. If we don't want to go there (I don't really want to), just accept that an example from India does not invalidate a generic answer for the rest of the world.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper It's just that the whole thing reads as being specific to India and nothing suggests that what you call an “example” is merely that. And I am not the only one to read it that way, as the comments and upvotes testify. The accepted answer is not much better in that it does not produce actual evidence but it does at least imply this exists everywhere.

Comment: "Honestly, what is the huge deal with that?" Well, I'm Italian and I've never even heard of such a thing. If you need some cash (less than 500€, or 1000 at most), you need to go to an ATM, as no one is coming to your place carrying the money. If you need *a lot* of cash, like 50,000, it's such an unusual situation that I think you really have to go to your bank and talk to them. I guess that in some countries this service is common, but in others it absolutely isn't.

Comment: @FabioTurati Based on your comment, I have removed the snide comment. I must admit I honestly thought the OP was living under a rock or something, and it almost sounded like, "I saw a super-rich guy withdraw money from an ATM, how did he do that?" I have now come to realize that this facility which is pretty much mundane over here, isn't so in other countries!

Comment: @MaskedMan The point is that the service requires a person to bring the cash from the bank to the home.  That person has to be paid.  In India this is very cheap so the banks will offer this service to the middle classes; in the US labour is very expensive so the banks only offer this service to the very wealthy.

Comment: @Martin Uhm, given that the person who comes with the cash is at a rank at least 2 levels above entry level in the concierge company, is accompanied by a security guard with a licensed gun, and has the trip insured, your claim of this service being cheap sounds rather funny to me. It may be so in comparison to the US though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60785/discussion-on-answer-by-masked-man-how-do-the-rich-and-wealthy-withdraw-from-acc).

Comment: @MaskedMan Key issue you are missing here is that, I don't have exact figures but I think that cash accounts for far higher proportion of transactions in India than in US. Which means such service (cash deliveried to your home) is actually *less* needed thus prevalent in "more advanced" countries.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who has that kind of money to blow probably has a CPA with a power of attorney who could provide such a service.

I don't have that kind of money but I do have a CPA with a POA who would gladly charge me and arm and a leg to deliver money to me.

Comment: The cost of providing the service is probably about the same, therefore either the super-rich person is being charged but doesn't care, or they are providing enough profit (e.g. overpaying) to their CPA that said CPA absorbs the cost.

Comment: of course the person making the withdrawl is absorbing the cost one way or another. how that cost is itemized seems irrelevant.

Comment: I've had this much disposable capital before. Yeah unless you have at least a couple million USD or Euro or equivalent capital you're not going to be retiring unless you're pretty old.. You can't even do that living in a trailer park or apartments..